# Can I install llncs with tlmgr?

Tags: packages, installing, texlive

llncs is a package created by Springer, available from the Springer authors' instructions page. tlmgr doesn't find it online. I have installed it many times by hand, and find it annoying. I have to download the zip file and copy everything into the right place.

Is there a way to "point" tlmgr to the downloaded zip file and let it do the installation work for me, the way yum does for downloaded rpms?

Comment: basically no, in the same way yum can't install a random zip file, it wants an rpm with the extra metadata of where to install stuff and dependencies etc. Why do you have to install it many times? If you install it in your local texmf tree it should survive texlive updates and not need installing until you have a new machine, if it is one off use on different machines, you don't have to copy everything into the right place just dump the contents of the zip file in the local directory.

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: I am using vanilla texlive. Since in manual install, I am making the decision where to put each file from the zip archive based on its extension, I hoped that tlmgr can do this too.

Comment: Please ask Springer to upload the package to CTAN under a license acceptable for TeXLive - then it would probably be distributed by TeXLive. Or Springer could set up a TeXLive repository of their own.

Answer (score 3):

As already given in the above comments, no there is no way. And as long as Springer uses a restrictive/non-free copyright it will not show up in TeX Live.

tlmgr can download packages that are in the format it expects, with .tar.xz as extension, from the command line.

The reason is that converting an arbitrary package to TDS format is far from trivial. We have a long script with hundreds of cases that tries to achieve this. We use it to update the internal subversion repository of TeX Live.

What you can do are the following options:

- upload it to tlcontrib if the license allows it
- create your own tlp, by putting all foles in the right place in a otherwise empty trxmf tree. Then add a tlpobj file (see your installation for examples). Pack it ul with tar and xz. Then you can keep it somewhere and simply tell tlmgr to install it from the command line

Maybe we can create a script that automates that ...?

Comment: How hard would it be extend tlmgr to not only handle "packages" (i.e. complete tlpobj), but also "ports" (i.e. tlbs that only point to downloadable items) in the OpenBSD speak?

Comment: Hi Martin - sorry for the late answer, I was busy at TUG 2013 in Tokyo. I don't understand what you mean? You already can install a .tar.xz which consitutates a tlpobj container from the command line. Do you want to know if I can also to `tlmgr install --file http://url/tlpkg.tar.xz`? Or do you want to know whether the repackaging can be included in `tlmgr`?

Comment: AFAIK tlmgr only handles self-contained packages: they must contain the metadata _and_ the files. How hard would it be to separate the metadata and the files? A "port" would then ony contain the metadata and urls to the files (in OpenBSD a "port" is just a makefile plus patches).

Comment: Hmmm, not supported at all by now, and I wouldn't know for now how to go there. And more, would it really be useful? CTAN does not provide all files, often dtx have to be compiled etcetc. If you are really interested, switch over to email!